# Technique for multiple users on same datasets

Tags: php, database, concurrency, web, multi-user

This is more a learning question than coding, but I'm certain it's a common issue for anyone developing administration systems or applications in php/mysql/js etc.

I've developed quite a complex application that lets users upload images, and define hotspots in them with associated actions. The images are stored in a table, and the actions in another, with json data for every action in a text field. It's a magazine style format that is used by a custom reading application. However, like I say, the problem is generic.

Basically, my fear is that if someone is editing the same image and set of actions at the same time, and they both submit changes, or if it was edited by someone else then there's a whole series of structures that potentially will fail on submission.

I don't want to implement a locking system, as the system is very wide ranging (links to other images, etc), and I think it's a bit ugly. I saw [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) (MSDN Multi-tenant architecture article) in another question, but it seems a little overwhelming and specialised for sql server.

So - what are the terms for data and system architecture here that I can investigate, or are there some good articles to do with this topic that people can recommend? Specifically for php/web world would be great!

--

I'm still looking for good responses on this question. Found out meanwhile that the general term is 'Concurrency', but technique is the important thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN changecount BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

for all relevant tables. Then whenever you want to submit a change, use not only

```
UPDATE tablename SET whatever WHERE id=whatever
```

but

```
UPDATE tablename SET whatever, changecount=changecount+1 WHERE id=whatever AND changecount=the_changecount_you_remembered_from_loading_the_object
```

now if a user submits a change, it will update the changecount - another user submitting a change to the same object, but loaded from older state, can be told "another user has just changed blah blah"

Comment: Thanks Eugen, that's helpful, but I'd like to know a bit more about common patterns that people use too. I could hash together something, like what you suggest, and it'd be ok, but with such a common problem, would be cool to know what other approaches were developed. Voted up :)

Comment: @danp Thanks, I'm quite curious about other solutions too - the above is what we (nearly allways) use, but there are definitly more ways to skin a cat.